# Writing a sorting function to sort an array of pointers, pointing to structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, bubble-sort

I'm writing a function to sort an array of pointers, pointing to structures, based on the value of a zip code. I found a sort function online (it's my first time writing a sort function) and thought I would play around with it and see what happens and I keep getting the error "Array type 'char[7] is not assignable' and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Thank you.

```
struct personCatalog {
char name[50];
char address[50];
char cityState[50];
char zipCode[7];
} ;

#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void bubble_sort(struct personCatalog *arrayOfPointers[]){
    int num1 = 0;

    while (arrayOfPointers[num1] != NULL) {
    atoi(arrayOfPointers[num1++]->zipCode);
    }

        int progress = 0;

        do {
            int i;
            progress = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < num1 - 2; ++i) {
                if (arrayOfPointers[i]->zipCode > arrayOfPointers[i + 1]->zipCode) {
                    struct personCatalog  temp = *arrayOfPointers[i];
                    arrayOfPointers[i] = arrayOfPointers[i + 1];
                    arrayOfPointers[i + 1] = &temp;

                    progress = 1;
                }
            }
        } while (progress);
    }
```

[image: Error I'm receiving]

Comment: `memcpy(temp, arrayOfPointers[i], sizeof(struct personCatalog));` the first argument is the culprit (in the other line the second, both times it's `temp`). You should pass a pointer: `&temp`. **But** you're `memcpy`ing the whole struct, you can have that easier, `temp = *arrayOfPointers[i];`, structs are assignable. In your original, you tried to assign to `temp->zipCode` (`temp` was a pointer then). That was what caused the first error. If you only want to swap the `zipCode`s, you must `memcpy(&(temp.zipCode), &(arrayOfpointers[i].zipCode), sizeof temp.zipCode);` etc.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I updated the code using your recommendations and I got an error I've never seen before. I'm trying to upload a screenshot of it.

Comment: The problem that immediately jumps out is that `temp` is a local variable, so `&temp` becomes a dangling pointer after the `if` finishes. With a `struct personCatalog temp;`, you need to swap the pointed-to values, so `*arrayOfPointers[i] = *arrayOfPointers[i+1];` etc. But since you have an array of pointers, it's less work to just swap the pointers, so use a pointer as temporary variable, `struct personCatalog *temp = arrayOfPointers[i]; ... arrayOfPointers[i+1] = temp;`.

Comment: I have no idea where the reference to `_sortPerson` may come from, you're not calling a `sortPerson` function in the code here at all.

Comment: @DanielFischer: oops, it appears I almost duplicated your comment in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Daniel. I really appreciate it. I'll do some work on it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: But, the message says the symbol is undefined for architecture x86_64, are you maybe using a library that is compiled for 32-bits?

Comment: @wildplasser You know what they say about great minds.

Comment: I'm calling the function in the main. I just didn't want to post all of the code being that it's in 6 different files.

Comment: I found out the problem, the sort function was titled differently in the header file than the c file. I got the program to work correctly. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array consists of pointers. So the temp thing you are using to swap them should also be a pointer.

```
    for (i = 0; i < num1 - 1; ++i) {
            if ( strcmp( arrayOfPointers[i]->zipCode
                       , arrayOfPointers[i + 1]->zipCode
                       ) > 1) {
                struct personCatalog  *temp ;
                temp = arrayOfPointers[i];
                arrayOfPointers[i] = arrayOfPointers[i + 1];
                arrayOfPointers[i + 1] = temp;

                progress = 1;
            }
        }
```

Also, the loop condition `i < num1-2` was wrong. Should be num1 -1, IMO.

Update: it appears zipcode is a textstring, so I replaced ">" by "strcmp()"

Comment: Before the function I changed zip code to an int using atoi().

Comment: But you ignore the return value. The atoi() is effectively a no-op.

Comment: Oh, I guess I was confused on how it worked. What would be a proper implementation of it?

Comment: I'm curious because I'm trying to sort the zip codes based on the lowest value.

Comment: You could do two things: 1) store the int *value* for the zipcode inside the structure (ou'll need to add another element to the struct) and assign to that, or 2) keep the ">" comparison, but wrap the zipcode operands each into an atio() function call.

Comment: Ok. I think I'll try option number 2. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The C language doesn't inherently know how to assign 7 chars to 7 other chars. It only allows you to assign one primitive type to another at a time:

```
zipCode[0] = temp[0]
zipCode[1] = temp[1];
// etc.
```

To copy arrays in C which are contiguous, like `zipCode`, you can use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(zipCode, temp, 7);
```

Also, it's possible that I misread your intent on my tiny screen, but you also shouldn't assign a struct pointer to zipCode either.

Comment: I tried to use memcpy and I got an error saying, "Unterminated function-like macro invocation." Do you know why? Thank you.

Comment: Update your code and comments above to reflect the new error in context. You should also `#include <string.h>` for `memcpy`.

Comment: There's a new error. I updated the code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The `memcpy` destination and source arguments must be addresses, so you can't pass `temp`, you must pass `&temp` or `temp->zipCode` if you want to copy to/from the `zipCode` array.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems with this code, but you're getting this error because you're trying to assign values to arrays in the highlighted lines; that's why it's complaining about assignment to array type `char[7]`. This doesn't make much sense, since you can't change the location of an array.  You can either swap the bytes with a call to `memcpy`, or, perhaps more idiomatically, change the definition of `struct personCatalog` such that `zipcode` is a true `char *` rather than a char array.

Comment: I tried to use memcpy and I got an error saying, "Unterminated function-like macro invocation." Do you know why? Thank you.

Comment: @user1681673 Apparently, `memcpy` is implemented as a macro in your implementation. How did you try to call it? Maybe you forgot a closing parenthesis?

Comment: Ah, I missed a closing parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: There's a new error, I updated the code. Thanks for the help.